# How do I specify the name of a joiner table in an EF many to many relationship?

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF Code First 6.2 With Dev Express XAF
In DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EF  the Event class has a many to many relationship with the Resource class.

If I make a new project using the Dev Express Wizard with Code First then the joiner table will be called ResourceEvents

However somehow in some migration my joiner table got renamed to be EventResources.

How do I set it back to what it should be?
I tried adding  the following to the DBContext

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().HasMany(x => x.Resources).WithMany(x => x.Events)
            .Map(
                x =>
                {
                    x.MapLeftKey("Event_ID");
                    x.MapRightKey("Resource_Key");
                    x.ToTable("ResourceEvents");
                });
```

this causes a migration to want to create

```
  public partial class ev : DbMigration
    {
  public override void Up()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ResourceEvents");
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.ResourceEvents", new[] { "Event_ID", "Resource_Key" });
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ResourceEvents");
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.ResourceEvents", new[] { "Resource_Key", "Event_ID" });
    }
```

}

Running the migration causes an error

```
Cannot find the object "dbo.ResourceEvents" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to add code to the migration to rename the table

```
RenameTable(name: "dbo.EventResources", newName: "ResourceEvents");
```

Having the fluent API seems important in letting EF know what the name of the table should be.